# Setting up a task in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, mocha.js

I am trying to setup a task in package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "unit-test": "mocha './test/unit/**/*.spec.js'",
 }
```

However when I run

```
npm run unit-test
```

the following errors are thrown in the console at the end of the run:

```
npm ERR! Darwin 16.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/shreya.vakil/.nvm/v6.9.5/bin/node" "/Users/d.bubble/.nvm/v6.9.5/bin/npm" "run" "unit-test"
npm ERR! node v6.9.5
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! myapp@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT unit-test: `mocha './test/unit/**/*.spec.js'`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

However, if I change the command to

```
"scripts" : {
 "unit-test": "mocha './test/unit/**/*.spec.js'; exit 0",
}
```

this error is not thrown. However, I am not sure if this is the right approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original behavior is correct, if a little ugly - if your tests fail, Mocha returns an exit code of 1, which is technically an error. Your second example makes the output prettier, but it'll cause you issues if you try to integrate your build scripts into other tools (for example, [Travis](https://travis-ci.org/)), as they won't be able to detect when your tests fail.

The best solution to this would be to get rid of the `exit 0` and upgrade your version of NPM - [the output was made much shorter in v4.6.1](https://github.com/npm/npm/commit/65b9943e9424c67547b0029f02b0258e35ba7d26). You can do this by running the following command:

```
npm install npm -g
```